# using .cat.codes() within a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am segregating object type columns as below:

`non_num_cols = df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns`

Now, my non_num_cols contain values like `['education', 'capital-gain', 'race', 'sex', 'classification']`

I want to convert these with `cat.codes()` as in the below example:

```
df.education = df.education.astype('category').cat.codes
```

However, I want to do this using a "for" loop. The closest I've been able to get to this is:

```
df[non_num_cols] = df[non_num_cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))
```

But, I cannot use the .cat.codes() with this. It throws

> TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index education')

Any suggestions?

Comment: `.cat.codes()` -> `.cat.codes`. If something is not a function, do not call it.

Comment: @DyZ

Good catch. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
  for name in cat_columns:
    df[name] = df[name].astype('category')

  df[non_num_cols] = df[non_num_cols].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, I edited your answer to remove the "fluff" (see [tour]), here the focus is on the problem and its solutions. It's better to explain *why* your code solves the question. All the best! (edit: I'm just seeing user DYZ explained the issue in a comment below the question, anyway, it's best to have a proper answer)